# php replacing old code with DateTime class

Tags: php, class, datetime, time

I have a function that creates time intervals between two time marks. The function works but I'm struggling to upgrade from `strtotime()` and use the `DateTime` class.

Below is a patch of code I wrote without getting errors

```
$timestart = new DateTime("14:00:00");
$timestop = new DateTime("20:00:00");
$date_diff = $timestop->diff($timestart);
$time_diff = $date_diff->format('%H');
```

Next is the entire code untouched. I get `DateInterval could not be converted to int` erros using the code above. Please kindly advise how to correctly implement the class.

Live example: http://codepad.org/jSFUxAnp

```
function timemarks() 
    {       

        //times are actually retrieved from db
        $timestart = strtotime("14:00:00");
        $timestop = strtotime("20:00:00");

        $time_diff = $timestop - $timestart; //time difference

        //if time difference equals negative value, it means that $timestop ends second day 
        if ($time_diff <= 0) 
        {
            $timestop = strtotime( '+1 day' , strtotime( $row->timestop ) ); //add 1 day and change the timetsamp
            $time_diff = $timestop - $timestart;
        }

        //create interval
        $split = 3;
        $interval = $time_diff/$split;

        //get all timemarks
        $half_interval = $interval / 2;
        $mid = $timestart + $half_interval;     
        for ( $i = 1; $i < $split; $i ++) {
            //round intervals   
            $round_mid = round($mid / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60);
            $result .= date('H:i:s', $round_mid) . ", ";
            $mid += $interval;
        }       
        $round_mid = round($mid / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60);
        $result .= date('H:i:s', $round_mid);

        return $result;
    }
```

outputs `15:00:00, 17:00:00, 19:00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're using DateTime, these are just aliases for creating DateTime instances

The equivalent would look like this:

```
$timestart = new DateTime("14:00:00");
$timestop = new DateTime("20:00:00");
$date_diff = $timestop->diff($timestart);
$time_diff = $date_diff->format('%H');
```

So this has to work, I tested it and I got correct results!

Comment: Thanks I will update my code! The procedural style gives the same results it seems.

Comment: that patch of code works but added to the entire script I get `DateInterval could not be converted to int` errors. All the calculation use timestamp format so it's very complicated (for me at least) to change that to `DateTime`

Comment: Yeah I am over that code too, it's really kinda tricky. But you can call `$datetime->getTimestamp()`, that makes it a lot easier.

Comment: As I don't know what the real clue behind this calculation is, I can't rewrite that code. The return values are trivial, but I don't know why they're created. I think for this operation you can stick to your old code. `DateTime` is for real use of dates and times together, but what you do is simple maths. So I don't see a problem in that.

Comment: I think you're right. Maybe `DateTime`isn't meant for all that mess.